# Google App Engine: using JPA but receiving JDO errors

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

I'm using JPA in my project but receiving an exception related to JDO classes and I saw this in other occasions, also.

I don't want to know about this specific exception in the JDOStateManagerImpl class, I want to know if it's normal to receive exceptions related to JDO when using JPA or I'm messing with the configurations.

I know DataNucleus is the provider for both so I thought that even using JPA, JDO would be doing the job behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal to receive exceptions when things happen that the JPA spec says throw an exception for. A **nested** exception can be a JDO exception (or a DataNucleus exception or a lowlevel exception) since the *JDO bytecode enhancement contract* is utilised (that is the only part of JDO present here, and since it is a standardised bytecode enhancement contract is a very sensible thing to make use of instead of inventing a new contract).